# Jmeter || Error generating the report: java.lang.NullPointerException while running test from CMD

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to execute a test from CMD but getting following error :
[image: Error Details]

Command : jmeter -n -t D:\Users\load.test\Desktop\Performance\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\UserServices.jmx -l D:\Users\load.test\Desktop\Performance\apache-jmeter-5.5\PerformanceData\MICR_Project\MICR_TestResults\DebugOOM\DebugOOM_1.csv -e -o  D:\Users\load.test\Desktop\Performance\apache-jmeter-5.5\PerformanceData\MICR_Project\MICR_TestResults\DebugOOM\DebugOOM_1 -JURL=localhost -JPort=7058 -JUser=5 -JRampUp=1 -JDuration=900 -JRampUpSteps=1 -JOutputFileName=OutputOOM.jtl -JErrorFileName=ErrorOOM.jtl -JFlow1=100

What could be the possible reasons for this error as its not very informative.*emphasized text*

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException is related to generating the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), the dashboard generation fails because your test failed to execute at all - no [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) were run.

The reason why no Samplers were run can be found in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), the most "popular" reasons are:

1. The number of threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is 0
2. The test uses [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) for parameterization and the CSV file is not present.
3. The test uses a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and the plugin is not installed

Comment: There are no error logs in Jmeter.log and the csv and plugin are already in place.